# Statically set onLongClick Listener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

In xml layouts, one can set a onclick listener to any item using this syntax:

```
android:onClick="clicked"
```

implementing the function in the activity:

```
public void clicked(View v) {
...
}
```

This is great as it reduces code executed at run time. I've thus been on a quest to find the equivalent for `OnLongClick Listeners`. I've experimenting in XML and there is no android:onLongClick...

Is there a way to set the `onLongClick Listener` at compile time?
If not what are some strategies? Have an initial loading screen where the listeners get set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only event handler that has an XML attribute is `android:onClick`. All other event handlers are registered at runtime from Java code. Technically, even `android:onClick` is registered at runtime from Java code, but you do not have to write the Java code in question.

Comment: I'm curious, when exactly is the listener registered, then. When the view is inflated?

Comment: @Ian: Presumably. I haven't gone through the source code to try to find out, but that's a likely guess.